# Apple Push Notification Error (aps-environment)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have registered the app on iTunes connect. When I run the app on the device I get the following APNS error.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x19e890 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

I have used the same AppID and bundle identifier in the xCode project as well as the iTunes connect.

Also, I forgot to mention that the App is registered under a Enterprise developer profile and I am running it under my personal developer profile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have either not enabled Push Notifications in the Provisioning Portal, or you are not signing your app with the correct certificate that was created when you did enable Push Notifications.

Comment: After hours of debugging, my problem was that I used the wrong certificate to sign the application. After cleaning what I had in the Organiser -> Library -> Provisioning Profiles, app registered correctly. Thanks for giving me the direction!

Comment: just add a new device to Provision Profile and generate the certificate

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I ended up removing my Provisioning Profiles, on the provisioning portal clicked Edit and then Generate to have them freshly generated, then downloaded the needed Provisioning profiles and double-checked Code Signing Identity (in Build Settings).

Code Signing Identity looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l2hd.png